# Extract the parameter value from a slash separated url by removing extra characters in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, url-routing, laravel-routing

I am creating routes for my php server on laravel framework. How do I extract the proper parameter value from a slash-separated url by stripping the unnecessary bits?

When the url pattern is set in the form of 
        `Route::get('user/{event_id}',function ($event_id){return view('rsvp',['event_id'=>$event_id]);})->where(['event_id'=>'[0-9]+']);`

it is working exactly as expected. However, I want to parse a url in the form of `'user/event-description-here5_now-<event_id>` and achieve the same functionality. That is, I want to use the `event_id` in my php file and ignore the `event-description-here5_now` bit. How should I go about this?

Comment: if you have control over the route why not making it /description-here5_now/{even_id} if you don't have control check out php parse_str  with the use of substr you can get the event id if its constant number of characters

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, as the laravel route model binding works via a wildcard, and it does not work when trying to extract numbers from a url segment.

In order to make it work you will have to customize laravel route resolution logic:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding

something along the lines of:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Route::bind('eventslug', function ($value) {
        preg_match('/\d+/', strrev($value), $matches);
        return Event::find($matches[0]) ?? abort(404);
    });
}
```

Or try to tweak the url like:

`user/event-description-here5_now/{event_id}`